# Loop through rows and compare two columns and apply logic and change one column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax, data-science

I know the syntax is way off here but basically trying to nail down this function. Ultimately I want to compare the years in both these columns. If the year in the first column matches the year in the second column I then want to verify that one column has a year less than 2006 and if the year is less than 2006 I want to change that year's row to the year 2006.Functionally the if else statementbelow is what I want just need to nail down the syntax in pandas.

Data:
[image]

```
for index,row in product_df.iterrows():
    if row(product_df['inputs/ConstructionYearRoof']) = row(product_df['inputs/ConstructionYear']) and row(product_df['inputs/ConstructionYearRoof']) < 2006:
        row(product_df['inputs/ConstructionYearRoof']) = 2006
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You would not do this sort of thing with `.iterrows()`. One of the biggest tricks to get used to with pandas is to instead think about *selecting rows* and then performing *column operations*.

You would do this sort of thing with a boolean mask:

```py
# First select the rows you want by creating a boolean mask for each condition
mask1 = product_df['inputs/ConstructionYearRoof'] == product_df['inputs/ConstructionYear']
mask2 = product_df["inputs/ConstructionYearRoof"] < 2006
mask3 = mask1 & mask2

# Then use the mask to select only those rows at the column you want
# You are now setting the desired value on the whole column but only 
# on the selected rows.
product_df.loc[mask3, "inputs/ConstructionYearRoof"] = 2006
```

Comment: ahh yes makes perfect sense! thanks so much really appreciate it.

Comment: If it was helpful, could you award an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is good. Alternatively, you can wrap the logic inside a function and `apply` it on all rows of the df.

```py
def checkYear(row):
    return 2006 if row['inputs/ConstructionYearRoof'] == row['inputs/ConstructionYear'] and row['inputs/ConstructionYearRoof'] < 2006 else row['inputs/ConstructionYearRoof']
    
df['inputs/ConstructionYearRoof'] = df.apply(lambda x: checkYear(x), axis=1)
```